# Reactor not restartable while running multiple spiders

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm having some trouble running multiple spiders in a row and I couldn't find an answer that fixed my issue.

In my project I have multiple spiders, one of them can work on his own but, the following ones depend on the first one to have finished for the program to work correctly.

How can I make one spider run after the other? I tried doing something like this:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
import excelMerger

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())

process.crawl('urlClothes_spider')
process.start()
process.crawl('clothes_spider')
process.start()
process.crawl('finalClothes_spider')
process.start()
```

But after the first one finish I get a reactor not startable error.

I have also tried just putting the `.crawl` one after the other but it seems like that way the order is not followed, so the program does not work, something like this

```
process.crawl('urlClothes_spider')
process.crawl('clothes_spider')
process.crawl('finalClothes_spider')
```

Any ideas on how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow the sequential execution example in the [documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process):

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl('urlClothes_spider')
    yield runner.crawl('clothes_spider')
    yield runner.crawl('finalClothes_spider')
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!, Thanks!